# mac user agent styles overriding css

Tags: css, macos, drupal

this one has got me baffled. I'm working on a site in drupal 7 and I adding some padding to a input submit button on the site and the padding is not showing. it's being overridden by the user agent padding. I'm using mac os x mountain lion, and I've tried chrome, FF, safari, and opera, and NONE show the padding.
what's really strange is the padding IS showing on all my other computers in all browsers.
I tried linux FF and chrome, and windows 7 FF, chrome, and IE and the padding is showing fine.

so why the heck is the padding not showing in any browser on mac only??

if I use -webkit-appearance: none; on mac it shows in chrome, but that doesn't explain why the padding shows everywhere else w/o -webkit appearance: none;

is there a setting somewhere in mac pertaining to user agent stylesheets? I'm at a total loss on this one any help is GREATLY appreciated.thanks.

Comment: Well, webkit applies to only Safari and Chrome. I'm sure people could help if you provided any code.

Comment: well the button markup is: <input id="edit-go" class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Go" name="op"> and I'm trying to apply padding .form-submit { padding: 100px; } the button was created with the drupal form api. I don't think it's an issue with the code though as it works fine in all browsers on windows and linux and NO browsers on mac os x

Comment: messing around with this some more I discovered if I set the border-radius of the button to anything ex. border-radius: 1px; it removes the user agent styles and I can set the padding. this is easy to recreate, use a drupal 7 install and remove all styles from the search button then try and set a padding, fails. add a border radius and it removes user agent styles and you can set a padding, weird. this worked in firefox and chrome, but only on mac I cannot recreate this issue in linux or windows, double weird

Comment: share the link for us to review the code

Comment: I would share the link, but it's a password protected site in development so I can't, sorry